# scraping a table with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a table using scrapy
the table has tr > th > td elements 
here is the structure of the table

```
<table class="project-table">
<tr>
    <th>Price Per Sqft from</th>
    <td>AED 880</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <td class="project-typess">
    <a href="https://dxboffplan.com/new/apartments-for-sale-dubai/">Apartments</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

as you can notice some td elements has only text and others has an **a** elements 
here is my codes so far

```
def parse(self, response):
    # get the urls of each property
    urls = response.css('div.property-listing > a::attr(href)').extract()
    # for each property make a request to get the details of each property
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url = url , callback = self.parse_details )
    # go and get the next link for the next property
    next_page = response.css('div.property-listing > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    # to get the details of the property we go throught a life cycle
    yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page , callback = self.parse )

def parse_details(self , response):
    for item in response.css('table.project-table> tr '):
        var = DxbItem()
        var['item']             = item.css('th::text').extract()[0]
        var['value']            = item.css('td::text').extract()[0]
        # i've tried everything i know but nothing works 
        if not var['value']:
            var['value']        = item.css('td>a::text').extract()[0]
        yield var
```

i need to get v['value']  IndexError: list index out of range
i tried this too

```
    for item in response.css('table.project-table> tr '):
        var = DxbItem()
        var['item']             = item.css('th::text').extract()[0]
        a                       = item.css('td::text').extract()[0] # 
        b                       = item.css('td>a::text').extract()[0]
        var['value']            = a + b # to concatenate 2 lists 
        yield var
```

Comment: Maybe, you can try get just this: item.css('td>a::text').extract()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In documentation, you can search by `extract_first()` method.

> However, using .extract_first() avoids an IndexError and returns None when it doesn’t find any element matching the selection.